# How to Commit code into SVN from Linux server?

Tags: linux, svn, commit

How we can connect to SVN repository from Linux server. I want to connect to svn repository from linux server for committing code. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Check this https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/04/svn-command-examples/

Comment: Install svn on the server and use the svn commands.

Answer (score 2):

First I assume that the SVN repository is already created since you just want to get code and commit to it.

But basically as the comments describe there is not much to it.
You will need SVN (the command) and a Username and Password.

Again, I assume you have all of these things ready.

First thing you need to do is to check-out the repository so that you have the code on your local server. Once you have to code, then you can start to edit/add and change it and then commit it back.

```
svn co https://www.remotesvnserver.com/svn/project projectname
```

*"co" stands for "Check Out" witch is the equivalent of "Clone" when we are talking GIT.*

Now that you have checked out your SVN project, you can begin to edit and change it as you like (granted you have the permissions)

```
edit some.file (make changes to a file)
svn commit -m "My change info"
```

I won't begin to talk about if you add files, delete files or rename files.
You will need to look into SVN documentation for that, but again I assume that you already know these things as you just wanted to connect to a SVN repository.

I would recommend looking into some of the documentation Apache has on SVN.
(Apache Foundation is the project maintainer of SVN)

- https://subversion.apache.org
- https://subversion.apache.org/quick-start

Full SVN manual
- http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.html

Answer (score -1):

https://openoffice.apache.org/svn-basics.html
You can find details of various SVN commands here.